# python: data cleaning - detect pattern for fraudulent email addresses

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I am cleaning a data set with fraudulent email addresses that I am removing.

I established multiple rules for catching duplicates and fraudulent domains. But there is one screnario, where I can't think of how to code a rule in python to flag them.

So I have for example rules like this:

```
#delete punction
df['email'].apply(lambda x:''.join([i for i in x if i not in string.punctuation]))    

#flag yopmail
pattern = "yopmail"
match = df['email'].str.contains(pattern)
df['yopmail'] = np.where(match, 'Y', '0')

#flag duplicates
df['duplicate']=df.email.duplicated(keep=False)
```

This is the data where I can't figure out a rule to catch it. Basically I am looking for a way to flag addresses that start the same way, but then have consecutive numbers in the end.

```
abc7020@gmail.com
abc7020.1@gmail.com
abc7020.10@gmail.com
abc7020.11@gmail.com
abc7020.12@gmail.com
abc7020.13@gmail.com
abc7020.14@gmail.com
abc7020.15@gmail.com
attn1@gmail.com
attn12@gmail.com
attn123@gmail.com
attn1234@gmail.com
attn12345@gmail.com
attn123456@gmail.com
attn1234567@gmail.com
attn12345678@gmail.com
```

Comment: To clarify - which email addresses in the examples you provided would you want to flag as fraudulent?

Comment: All of those examples are fraudulent

Comment: So abc@gmail.com would be OK, but anything like abc1, abc12,.. would be fraudulent? And those would only be fraudulent if abc@gmail.com exists?

Comment: @jeangelj What is 'yopmail' and what does it have to do with the data?

Comment: It may be worth only allowing emails addresses from a whitelist, requiring verification as well as blocking multiple registrations from the same IP. You can write regex rules all day but anyone with a beer and some free time could work around that.

Comment: @COLDSPEED yopmail is a disposable domain; it's just a pattern I found

Comment: @Ipiner I totally agree; unfortunately that's the datasets I receive; I asked for some rules to be implemented on the front-end, but for now I have to automate the process when cleaning the dataset or I spent 3 days on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution isn't efficient, nor pretty. But check it out and see if it works for you @jeangelj. It definitely works for the examples you provided. Good luck!

```
import os
from random import shuffle
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

emails = [... ...] # for example the 16 email addresses you gave in your question
shuffle(emails) # everyday i'm shuffling
emails = sorted(emails) # sort that shit!
names = [email.split('@')[0] for email in emails]

T = 0.7 # <- set your string similarity threshold here!!

split_indices=[]
for i in range(1,len(emails)):
    if SequenceMatcher(None, emails[i], emails[i-1]).ratio() < T:
        split_indices.append(i) # we want to remember where dissimilar email address occurs

grouped=[]
for i in split_indices:
    grouped.append(emails[:i])
grouped.append(emails[i:])
# now we have similar email addresses grouped, we want to find the common prefix for each group
prefix_strings=[]
for group in grouped:
    prefix_strings.append(os.path.commonprefix(group))

# finally
ham=[]
spam=[]
true_ids = [names.index(p) for p in prefix_strings]
for i in range(len(emails)):
    if i in true_ids:
        ham.append(emails[i])
    else:
        spam.append(emails[i])

In [30]: ham
Out[30]: ['abc7020@gmail.com', 'attn1@gmail.com']

In [31]: spam
Out[31]: 
['abc7020.10@gmail.com',
 'abc7020.11@gmail.com',
 'abc7020.12@gmail.com',
 'abc7020.13@gmail.com',
 'abc7020.14@gmail.com',
 'abc7020.15@gmail.com',
 'abc7020.1@gmail.com',
 'attn12345678@gmail.com',
 'attn1234567@gmail.com',
 'attn123456@gmail.com',
 'attn12345@gmail.com',
 'attn1234@gmail.com',
 'attn123@gmail.com',
 'attn12@gmail.com']  

# THE TRUTH YALL!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to do this; example below:

```
import re

a = "attn12345@gmail.comf"
b = "abc7020.14@gmail.com"
c = "abc7020@gmail.com"
d = "attn12345678@gmail.com"

pattern = re.compile("[0-9]{3,500}\.?[0-9]{0,500}?@")

if pattern.search(a):
    print("spam1")

if pattern.search(b):
    print("spam2")

if pattern.search(c):
    print("spam3")

if pattern.search(d):
    print("spam4")
```

If you run the code you will see:

```
$ python spam.py 
spam1
spam2
spam3
spam4
```

The benefit to this method is that its standardized (regular expressions) and that you can adjust the strength of the match easily by adjusting the values within `{}`; which means you can have a global configuration file where you set/adjust the values. You can also adjust the regular expression easily without having to rewrite code.

Comment: Thank you - What is I have a user anna213@gmail.com and this is a legitimate user, but attn12, attn123, attn1234, attn12345 is not and I only want to catch those

Comment: @bbb31 ..or use CAPTCHA if possible.

Answer (score 1):

First take a look at regexp question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471177/python-check-if-the-last-characters-in-a-string-are-numbers)

Second, try to filter email address like that:

```
# Let's email is = 'attn1234@gmail.com'
email = 'attn1234@gmail.com'
email_name = email.split(',', maxsplit=1)[0]
# Here you get email_name = 'attn1234
import re
m = re.search(r'\d+$', email_name)
# if the string ends in digits m will be a Match object, or None otherwise.
if m is not None:
    print ('%s is good' % email)
else:
    print ('%s is BAD' % email)
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually looked at that regex question before I posted my question; I didn't feel the answers were flexible enough for all of the iterations I am facing, but thank you very much for referencing it; I will test your solution now; how would this differentiate between a legitimate email like john1988@gmail.com and attn12, attn123, attn1234, etc?

Comment: How many unique addresses are you processing? If not way too much, then I think that you might combine two approaches: define a list() for used (unique) emails and after regexp-catching those ending with digits, check them like @dman considered. Although,  john1988@gmail.com is stiil a problem, because  john1989@gmail.com looks valid, too.

Comment: about 100,000 emails at once, every month different ones - I don't think it's possible to define a list, that would apply every month if I understood correctly

Comment: @jeangelj You might define and populate that list in runtime. Start with empty one, then append there 'good' addresses. On each filtering iteration, drop e-mails with lots of numbers, and then fine-filter using fuzz.partial_ratio() with every element of that list to detect frauds. If e-mail address ratio says it's  'good', then append it to that list, so there will be known-as-good addresses. (But this might be not so fast when the list is big).

Answer (score 1):

You could pick a diff threshold using edit distance (aka [Levenshtein distance](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1501/Pruhs/Spring2006/assignments/editdistance/Levenshtein%20Distance.htm)). In python:

```
$pip install editdistance
$ipython2
>>> import editdistance
>>> threshold = 5 # This could be anything, really
>>> data = ["attn1@gmail.com...", ...]# set up data to be the set you gave
>>> fraudulent_emails = set([email for email in data for _ in data if editdistance.eval(email, _) < threshold])
```

If you wanted to be smarter about it, you could run through the resulting list and, instead of turning it into a set, keep track of how many other email addresses it was near - then use that as a 'weight' to determine fake-ness.

This gets you not only the given cases (where the fraudulent addresses all share a common start and differ only in numerical suffix, but additionally number or letter padding eg at the beginning or in the middle of an email address.

Answer (score 1):

```
ids = [s.split('@')[0] for s in email_list]
det = np.zeros((len(ids), len(ids)), dtype=np.bool)
for i in range(len(ids)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(ids)):
        mi = ids[i]
        mj = ids[j]
        if len(mj) == len(mi) + 1 and mj.startswith(mi):
            try:
                int(mj[-1])
                det[j,i] = True
                det[i,j] = True
            except:
                continue

spam_indices = np.where(np.sum(det, axis=0) != 0)[0].tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test it now

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea on how to solve this:

fuzzywuzzy

Create a set of unique emails, for-loop over them and compare them with  fuzzywuzzy.
Example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 

   for email in emailset:

      for row in data:
         emailcomp = re.search(pattern=r'(.+)@.+',string=email).groups()[0] 
         rowemail = re.search(pattern=r'(.+)@.+',string=row['email']).groups()[0] 
         if row['email']==email:
                  continue

          elif fuzz.partial_ratio(emailcomp,rowemail)>80:
                  'flagging operation'
```

I took some liberties with how the data is represented, but I feel the variable names are mnemonic enough for you to understand what I am getting at. It is a very rough piece of code, in that I have not thought through how to stop repetitive flagging.

Anyways, the elif part compares the two email addresses without @gmail.com (or any other email e.g. @yahoo.com), if the ratio is above 80 (play around with this number) use your flagging operation.
For example:

```
fuzz.partial_ratio("abc7020.1", "abc7020")
```

*100*

Comment: Hi! No worries, I don't downvote somebody taking time to help me. Thank you very much for this idea - I will definitely try it; it actually might be a great solution, I just want to make sure it doesn't mark emails that are legitimate as spam

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to approach it, that should be pretty efficient.
We do it by grouping the email address in lengths, so that we only need to check if each email address matches the level down, by a slice and set membership check.

The code:

First, read in the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

string = '''
abc7020@gmail.com
abc7020.1@gmail.com
abc7020.10@gmail.com
abc7020.11@gmail.com
abc7020.12@gmail.com
abc7020.13@gmail.com
abc7020.14@gmail.com
abc7020.15@gmail.com
attn1@gmail.com
attn12@gmail.com
attn123@gmail.com
attn1234@gmail.com
attn12345@gmail.com
attn123456@gmail.com
attn1234567@gmail.com
attn12345678@gmail.com
foo123@bar.com
foo1@bar.com
'''

x = pd.DataFrame({'x':string.split()})
#remove duplicates:
x = x[~x.x.duplicated()]
```

We strip off the @foo.bar part, and then filer to only those that end with a number, and add on a 'length' column:

```
#split on @, expand means into two columns
emails =  x.x.str.split('@', expand = True)
#filter by last in string is a digit
emails = emails.loc[:,emails.loc[:,0].str[-1].str.isdigit()]
#add a length of email column for the next step
emails['lengths'] = emails.loc[:,0].str.len()
```

Now, all we have to do, is take each length, and length -1, and see if the length. with it's last character dropped, appears in a set of the n-1 lengths (and, we have to check if the opposite is true, in case it is the shortest repeat):

```
#unique lengths to check
lengths = emails.lengths.unique()
#mask to hold results
mask = pd.Series([0]*len(emails), index = emails.index)

#for each length
for j in lengths:
    #we subset those of that length
    totest = emails['lengths'] == j
    #and those who might be the shorter version
    against = emails['lengths'] == j -1
    #we make a set of unique values, for a hashed lookup
    againstset = set([i for i in emails.loc[against,0]])
    #we cut off the last char of each in to test
    tests = emails.loc[totest,0].str[:-1]
    #we check matches, by checking the set
    mask = mask.add(tests.apply(lambda x: x in againstset), fill_value = 0)
    #viceversa, otherwise we miss the smallest one in the group
    againstset = set([i for i in emails.loc[totest,0].str[:-1]])
    tests = emails.loc[against,0]
    mask = mask.add(tests.apply(lambda x: x in againstset), fill_value = 0)
```

The resulting mask can be converted to boolean, and used to subset the original (deduplicated) dataframe, and the indices should match the original indices to subset like that:

```
x.loc[~mask.astype(bool),:]
    x
0   abc7020@gmail.com
16  foo123@bar.com
17  foo1@bar.com
```

You can see that we have not removed your first value, as the '.' means it did not match - you can remove the punctuation first.