# Finding the lowest number that does not occur at the end of a string, in a tuple in a list

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples, each has a single string as element 0, in these strings I want to get out the final number, and then find the lowest (positive) number that is not in this list.

How do you do this?

E.g. for the list `tups`:

```
tups=[('.p1.r1.c2',),('.p1.r1.c4',),('.p1.r1.c16',)]
```

the final numbers are `2`, `4` and `16`, so the lowest unused number is `1`.

---

my attempt was this:

```
tups2= [tup[0] for tup in tups]         # convert tuples in lists to the strings with information we are interested in
tups3 = [tup .rfind("c") for tup in tups2] # find the bit we care about
```

I wasn't sure how to finish it, or if it was fast/smart way to proceed

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share the code you've written, and point out exactly what isn't working, what the error is?

Comment: I've made the changes you've asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really specify your problem but I'm guessing that getting the lowest unused number is the issue.
the solutions above is great but it just gets the lowest number in the list and not the lowest unused one.
I tried to make a list of all the unused numbers then getting the minimum value of it.

I hope that would help

```
tups=[('15.p1.r1.c2',),('.poj1.r1.c4',),('.p2.r4.c160',)]
numbers = []
unused_numbers = []
for tup in tups:
    words = tup[0].strip(".").split('.')
    digits_list = [''.join(x for x in i if x.isdigit()) for i in words]
    unused_numbers.extend(digits_list[:-1])
    numbers.append(digits_list[-1])
print(numbers)
print(min(unused_numbers))
```

Answer (score 3):

Where are you blocked? You can achieve that in basically two steps:

**Step 1: Create the list of numbers**

One way of doing this (inspired from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47859789/14953588)):

```
numbers = [int(s[0][len(s[0].rstrip('0123456789')):]) for s in tups]
```

In your example, `numbers` is `[2, 4, 16]`.

**Step 2: Find the lowest positive number that is not in this list**

```
x = 1
while x in numbers:
  x += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the same method Thibault D used to get a list of numbers:

```py
tups=[('.p1.r1.c2',),('.p1.r1.c4',),('.p1.r1.c16',)]
num = [int(i[0][len(i[0].rstrip('0123456789')):]) for i in tups]
```

However, I used an easier method to get the minimum number:

```py
min(num) - 1
```

This basically gets the lowest number in the list, and then subtracts 1 from it.